# Мультиязычность в django: не переводит фразы

Tags: python, django

Решил попробовать мультиязычность у себя на сайте.

Сделал настройки:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',

    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',

    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

##LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru' #en тоже пробовал

LANGUAGES = (
  ('ru', 'Russian'),
  ('en', 'English'),
)

LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
)
```

Набросал простейший view для экспериментов:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    val = _("мир")
    val = _("Hello World!")
    return HttpResponse(val)
```

urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
    url(r'^translate/', index),
]
```

Создал файл перевода через

```
django-admin makemessages -l ru
```

Выглядит он так:

```
# SOME DESCRIPTIVE TITLE.
# Copyright (C) YEAR THE PACKAGE'S COPYRIGHT HOLDER
# This file is distributed under the same license as the PACKAGE package.
# FIRST AUTHOR <EMAIL@ADDRESS>, YEAR.
#
#, fuzzy
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: PACKAGE VERSION\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2020-01-22 17:53+0300\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: YEAR-MO-DA HO:MI+ZONE\n"
"Last-Translator: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\n"
"Language-Team: LANGUAGE <LL@li.org>\n"
"Language: \n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=4; plural=(n%10==1 && n%100!=11 ? 0 : n%10>=2 && n"
"%10<=4 && (n%100<12 || n%100>14) ? 1 : n%10==0 || (n%10>=5 && n%10<=9) || (n"
"%100>=11 && n%100<=14)? 2 : 3);\n"
#: .\prime\views.py:12
msgid "мир"
msgstr "world"

#: .\prime\views.py:13
msgid "Hello World!"
msgstr "Привет мир"
```

Скомпилировал:

```
django-admin compilemessages
```

Ошибок не было. Файл `*.mo` создался. Но при загрузке страницы все равно "Hello world!". Вероятно, мне не нужно, как-то указать, на какой язык нужно перевести. Я пробовал по адресу `http://127.0.0.1:8000/translate/i18n/ru/`, но ничего не поменялось. Вероятно, я упускаю какую-то мелочь, но не могу ее увидеть.

Я даже пробовал напрямую во view вставлять внутрь `index()`:

```
from django.utils import translation
user_language = 'ru'
translation.activate(user_language)     
request.session[translation.LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY] = user_language
```

Но все впустую.

Comment: Что написано в `request.META['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']`?

Answer (score 2):

Можно сказать, что я нашел ответ на свой вопрос. И он лежал в [документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/translation/#the-set-language-redirect-view). Судя по всему я ожидал видеть подзаголовок наподобие "changing default settings", а на заголовок "The set_language redirect view" не обращал внимание, т.к. к `redirect` он, по моему мнению, никак не относился.

Итак, информацию о текущем языке джанго хранит в сессиях или кукисах, а не создает отдельные страницы с префиксами для каждого языка (как я почему-то думал). Далее - язык, указанный в `LANGUAGE_CODE` в settings.py (by default), судя по всему, не переводится вообще.

Для примера переключения между языками можно использовать следующую страничку, допустим `lang.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">

    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <title></title>

        <style>

        </style>

        <script>

        </script>

    </head>

    <body>

        {% load i18n %}

        <form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">

            {% csrf_token %}

            <select name="language">
                {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
                {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
                {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
                {% for language in languages %}
                    <option value="{{ language.code }}"{% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>
                        {{ language.name_local }} ({{ language.code }})
                    </option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>

            <input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Change' noop %}" />


        </form>

    </body>

</html>
```

С view `lang = lambda request: render(request, "lang.html")` и с соответствующим адресом в urls.py:

```
url(r'^lang/$', lang, name='lang'),
```

Так все работает. Моя проблема была в том, что я отправлял get запрос и не на тот адрес. Всем спасибо за участие